# find and return a pointer to a object in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, find

New to c++, not really sure where I'm going wrong. Still wrapping my head around ptrs.

I have a vector of profile objects. I want to find a particular object based on one of it's properties. Then I want to return that object. I don't want to make copies or anything of the object so I guess I will need to return a pointer to the particular object?

Here is my code:

```
Profile* profileManager::getProfile(const std::string& name)
{
    std::vector<Profile>::iterator it = std::find_if(allProfiles.begin(), allProfiles.end(), [name](Profile &p) { return p.getName() == name; });
    return it != allProfiles.end() ? *it : nullptr;
}
```

There's a few things wrong that I don't know how to fix up. I want to return null if there isn't a match found and let the caller handle it, how would I do this? I'm getting a incompatible type at the moment and I've tried to change the return it around a bit but had no luck. It also says it isn't of the right type. How do I get it to return a pointer to the profile if it is found?

Any help/advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If `*it` is a `Profile`, how would you get a `Profile*`? Other than that, it looks right to me.

Comment: Makes complete sense, I am breaking my head reading about ptrs.

Comment: Since it's not a vector of profile ptrs, just a vector of profile objects, I will just have to return the profile object. I do this by reference and no extra copies are made and all is well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return it != allProfiles.end() ? *it : nullptr;
```

This almost does what you want. The type of `*it` is a `Profile`. To get a pointer to it, just take the address: `&*it`

Also, some recommended changes.

1. <s>Make `getProfile` a constant method. It doesn't (and shouldn't) modify anything</s>.
   Having a constant overload of `getProfile` is a good idea, but you'll want to keep the mutable one too.
2. Have the lambda parameter be a constant reference `(const Profile &p)`. This is also necessary if you make the above change.
3. You don't need to capture `name` by value. Capturing it by reference saves copying. `[&name]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the changes you suggested.

I almost have it working except for one small thing. Excuse any ignorance, I'm sure it's probably simple but learning about ptrs is making my head hurt haha.

When I try to use this getter method I get a conversion error. 
`'Profile::getRealm' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Profile' to 'Profile &'`

[Here's how I'm trying to use it](https://pastebin.com/0H05j2By) and here's the code that I'm using 
[the code.](https://pastebin.com/hyaZCTW4)

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: @user3238415 Ah, an oversight on my part. if `getProfile` is `const`, you'll have to return a `const Pointer*`, which means you can only call `const` methods on it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. 1 more question if possible. I have a lot of reading to do. :)

Would you be able to give me a quick explantion of why `&*it` made it work? My guess is that adding the `&` made it so it returned the address of the derefernced iterator instead of the dereferenced iterator itself, which was a object. Am I close? :)

Comment: @user3238415 Yes. `*` on an iterator will get the object it points to, so `&` will then get the address of the object.